# Getting a gtk slider to work in a popup menu?

Tags: ruby, gtk3

For some reason when I add a slider (scale) to a popup menu it doesn't work. It shows but doesn't move. How can I get the slider to work? Just put this in a `Gtk::Window`:

```
require 'gtk3' #gtk2 will probably work 

class VolumeButton <  Gtk::Button
  def initialize
    super()
    @theme = Gtk::IconTheme.default
    self.image = Gtk::Image.new(@theme.load_icon("audio-volume-high", 16, :force_svg))
    @menu = Gtk::Menu.new
    @menu.width_request = 200
    @item = Gtk::MenuItem.new
    @slider = Gtk::Scale.new(:horizontal, 0, 100, 1)
    @item.add(@slider)
    @menu.append(@item)
    @menu.show_all # this makes it show
    self.signal_connect "button-release-event" do |widget, event|
      @menu.popup(nil, nil, event.button, event.time)
    end
  end
end
```